# Is every field the field of fractions of an integral domain?

Tags: fields

Is every field the field of fractions of an integral domain which is not itself a field?

What about the field of real numbers?

Comment: Yes, every field is its own field of fractions!

Comment: You' re write.I didn't mean the trivial case so i changed the question.

Comment: Then no: pick any field with a prime number of elements.

Comment: Thank you again.
What about infinite fields?And the field of real numbers?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Every field $F$ of characteristic zero or of prime characteristic
but not algebraic over its prime field
is the field of fractions of a proper subring of $F$.
But no algebraic extension of $\mathbb F_p$ is, since its only subrings are fields.

If $F$ is not an algebraic extension of some $\mathbb F_p$
then $F$ contains a subring $A$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$
or $\mathbb F_p[X]$. Each of these rings $A$ has a nontrivial
valuation $v$. The valuation $v$ can be prolonged to $F$.
Its valuation ring is a proper subring of $F$ whose quotient field
is $F$.

Comment: Variant of the argument: let $B$ be a transcendence basis of $F$. Let $A\subset F$ be the subring generated by $B$. This is a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$, or a nontrivial polynomial ring over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Now take the integral closure of $A$ in $F$.

Comment: The existence of a prolongation of a valuation to a non algebraic extension field doesn't sem to be mentioned in the standard references (Atiyah, Bourbaki, Matsumura,...). A proof is provided [here](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/Math8410Ex2.4David.pdf).